# Why do eletronic circuit's fry with high levels of Exposure to ionizing radiation

Tags: electric-circuits, nuclear-physics

I've seen a similar question asked on this Exchange except it didn't concern electronic circuits instead it focused on electromagnetic radiation, and after seeing the Chernobyl series, yes i'm that late, **what causes malfunction of electronic circuits that are exposed to high levels of ionizing radiation**(im assuming, gama ray's and X rays, because alpha particles wouldn't penetrate a plastic enclosure and beta ones would be blocked off by lead enclosures).

We're assuming that the circuit's are all using "solid state" components so we're gonna asume the circuit has some basic carbon/copper resistor's, ceramic/tantalum caps, etc...

The only theory i can think of that can fry a chip like that would be if the ionizing radiation hit only a portion of the chip making one side very positive creating a huge Tension differential like 50 volts that would fry your typical 5-9 volt rated circuit but again the radiation is all enveloping on the series meaning that it wouldn't strike at a specific point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ionizing radiation creates many electron-hole pairs. If the circuit is powered on, these make the chip material highly conductive and short-circuits everything. A large current flows, the chip heats up and is destroyed.

Comment: what would be a good way of protecting said circuit then?

Comment: Lots of lead...?

Comment: well then i need to ask here two more questions